# Use kafka-avro-console-producer with a schema already in the schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I would like to use the `kafka-avro-console-producer` with the schema registry. I have big schemas (over 10k chars) and I can't really past them as a command line argument. Besides that I'd like to use the schema registry directly so I can use a specific schema id.

I'm thinking about something like this, but it doesn't work:

```sh
kafka-avro-console-producer \
 --broker-list <broker-list> \
 --topic <topic>  \
 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
 --property value.schema=`curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/419`
```

Comment: What you wrote looks fine. What does the curl command output on its own? Is that cut off?

Comment: It's not cut off, but I it looks like the inner payloads are strings rather than nested json objects (note the backslash before the quote) : `{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"...`. Also my schema has got a doc that contains single and double quote as well as * which gets interpreted weirdly by bash.

Comment: You need to download `jq`, then you can use `curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/419 | jq .schema `

Comment: Interesting, but schema is still a string rather than a json object: `{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"`. I would have to parse it and dump it as json again

Comment: OK, so what I need is `curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/419 | jq -r .schema`. I'm still having issue because * are expended to the content of the current directory.

Comment: Where are you getting `*` from? Can you try `value.schema="$(curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/419 | jq -r .schema)"`? Basically, you need to quote the `*` somehow

Comment: It works, thanks. The `*` are coming from the java style comments in the schema, eg: `/** */`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### For the current version of the CLI tool

```sh
kafka-avro-console-producer \
 --broker-list <broker-list> \
 --topic <topic>  \
 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
 --property value.schema.id=419
```

### For older version

You'll need to extract the schema from the API request using jq, for example

```
value.schema="$(curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/419 | jq -r .schema)"
```

Comment: This works fine but weirdly enough, on one of my topics I get "InvalidConfigurationException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409" which makes no sense since I am specifically not registering any schema but using an existing one.

Comment: @cen Are you using a file or the ID property? I would only expect that error when using a file

Comment: ID property. That is what makes it weird.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the property `value.schema.id`:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
 --broker-list <broker-list> \
 --topic <topic>  \
 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
 --property value.schema.id=419
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my version of `kafka-avro-console-producer`, I suspect it's too old and doesn't support it.

Comment: Where can I find all available properties for the `kafka-avro-console-producer` and `kafka-avro-console-consumer`? I failed to do that in the official docs

Comment: Here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/kafka-commands.html#produce-avro-records

Comment: @zza You should be able to pass `--help` to both commands

Comment: Yes, but `--help` doesn't give you the properties available to be configured, only the `--property` parameter itself is mentioned there, as well as in the examples page mentioned above only some properties were demonstrated. That is why I asked where, i.e. you found out about the `value.schema.id` property, because it was not mentioned anywhere

Comment: @ZZa personally, I reviewed the PR for the feature, and the code is open source, so you could find it there... I'm not sure about the docs or help output