# Can i specify only schema id in kafka avro producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to produce avro type message on kafka. Is there a way to use schema id registered ins schema registry instead of specifying schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On previous versions you couldn't, but in the meanwhile it became possible to do so like this (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582230/use-kafka-avro-console-producer-with-a-schema-already-in-the-schema-registry)):

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
 --broker-list <broker-list> \
 --topic <topic>  \
 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
 --property value.schema.id=419
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

But you can download the schema from the registry given the ID, then use that to create a message.

However, if you already have an Avro object, it already has a schema and the Avro serializer will extract it for you and replace it with an ID