# Producer Avro data from Windows with Docker

Tags: windows, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm following [How to transform a stream of events](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/transform-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html#initialize-the-project) tutorial.
Everything works fine until topic creation part:

Under title **Produce events to the input topic**:

```
docker exec -i schema-registry /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --topic raw-movies --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --property value.schema="$(< src/main/avro/input_movie_event.avsc)"
```

I'm getting:

> <: The term '<' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What would be proper way of calling Avro schema file in `--property value.schema` ?

All Confluent Kafka servers are running fine.
Schema registry is empty at this point:

```
PS C:\Users\Joe> curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects
[]
```

How can I register Avro file in Schema manually from CLI? I'm not finding options for that in Schema Registry API..

My thinking was - if I insert schema manually than I would be able to call it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582230/use-kafka-avro-console-producer-with-a-schema-already-in-the-schema-registry).

**EDIT 1**

Tried entering Avro file path as variable in Power shell like:

```
$avroPath = 'D:\ConfluentKafkaDocker\kafkaStreamsDemoProject\src\main\avro\input_movie_event.avsc'
```

And than executing:

```
docker exec -i schema-registry /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --topic raw-movies --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --property value.schema=$avroPath
```

But that didn't work.

**EDIT 2**

Manage to get it working with:

```
$avroPath = 'D:\ConfluentKafkaDocker\kafkaStreamsDemoProject\src\main\avro\input_movie_event.avsc'
docker exec -i schema-registry /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --topic raw-movies --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --property value.schema.file=$avroPath
```

But now I'm getting:

> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Error reading schema
> from
> D:\ConfluentKafkaDocker\kafkaStreamsDemoProject\src\main\avro\input_movie_event.avsc
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.getSchemaString(SchemaMessageReader.java:260)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.getSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:222)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.init(SchemaMessageReader.java:153)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:43)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)

**input_movie_event.avsc:**

```
{
  "namespace": "io.confluent.developer.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "RawMovie",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "id", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "genre", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

It's copy-pasted from example so I see not reason why it would be incorrectly formatted.

**EDIT 3**

Tried with forward slash since Power shell works now with it:

```
 value.schema.file=src/main/avro/input_movie_event.avsc
```

and than with backslash:

```
value.schema.file=src\main\avro\input_movie_event.avsc
```

I'm getting same error as in Edit 2 - so it looks like this flag `value.schema.file` is not working properly.

**EDIT 4**

tried with  `value.schema="$(cat src/main/avro/input_movie_event.avsc)"` as suggested [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1084#issuecomment-481780515):

Error I'm getting now is:

> [2022-04-05 10:17:24,135] ERROR Could not parse Avro schema
> (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaProvider)
> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
> ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name  at
> [Source: (String)"{   namespace: io.confluent.developer.avro,   type:
> record,   name: RawMovie,   fields: [     {name: id, type: long},
> {name: title, type: string},     {name: genre, type: string}   ] }";
> line: 1, column: 6]
> at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1427)
> at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1413)
> at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchema.(AvroSchema.java:70)
> at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaProvider.parseSchema(AvroSchemaProvider.java:54)
> at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema(SchemaProvider.java:63)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.parseSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:212)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.getSchema(SchemaMessageReader.java:224)
> at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.init(SchemaMessageReader.java:153)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:43)
> at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)

In error it says that it `was expecting double-quote to start field name` and also that  `name: id` and in file I have:

```
"fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": "long"},
        {"name": "title", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "genre", "type": "string"}
      ]
```

Why is it parsing it incorrectly, like there are not double-quotes when in file they are actually there?

**EDIT 6**

tried with `value.schema="$(type src/main/avro/input_movie_event.avsc)"`

since `type` is equivalent for `cat` on Windows - got same error as in Edit 5.
Tried with `get-content`  as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/434872/598150) - same error.

Comment: Overall, the instructions are Linux specific. Use WSL2, not Powershell, and you shouldn't get as many errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I register Avro file in Schema manually from CLI?

You would not use a Producer, or Docker.

You can use Postman and send POST request (or the Powershell equivalent of `curl`) to the /subjects endpoint, like the Schema Registry API documentation says for registering schemas.

---

After that, using `value.schema.id`, as linked, will work.

Or, if you don't want to install anything else, I'd stick with `value.schema.file`. That being said, you must start the container with this file (or whole `src\main\avro` folder) mounted as a Docker volume, which would not be referenced by a Windows path when you actually use it as part of a `docker exec` command. My linked answer referring to the `cat` usage assumes your files are on the same filesystem.

Otherwise, the exec command is being interpreted by Powershell, first, so input redirection won't work for `value.schema`, and `type` would be the correct CMD command, but `$()` syntax might not be, as that's for UNIX shells;

Related - [PowerShell: Store Entire Text File Contents in Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976646/powershell-store-entire-text-file-contents-in-variable)